# Lumia 520 won`t work - keeps restarting

Tags: lumia-520

My phone keeps restarting. I can start it, and swipe on the home screen, but if I wont to open any app or settings, or someone call, phone restarts.

I tried soft, hard reset and windows device recovery tool, but nothing helped me.

Is there any help for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Nokia Software Recovery Tool](http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/NokiaSoftwareRecoveryToolInstaller.exe) to try and reinstall your phone's firmware. If that doesn't work, try the [Windows Phone Recovery tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=525010)